# Why is data inside Arc<T> mutable?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a variable of `Arc<(TcpStream, SocketAddr)>` type (types in the tuple are from `std::net`) and I want to use `TcpStream` to call `read_to_string()` method. As I've read in the docs, `Arc<T>` data type is a reference to the type `T`, and it is not allowed to mutate `T` value inside the `Arc<T>`.

Here's my code:

```rust
let arced = Arc::<(TcpStream, SocketAddr)>::new(/*some var*/);
let mut unwraped = &arced.0; // It's not "&mut arced.0" since DerefMut isn't implemented for Arc.
let mut buf = String::new();
// But i can still use "unwraped" as mutable. Why?
unwraped.read_to_string(&mut buf);
```

And `read_to_string()` method requires a mutable reference to the struct:

```rust
fn read_to_string(&mut self, buf: &mut String) -> Result<usize>
```

How come that `TcpStream` from `arced` is mutable?

Comment: `Read` is [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-1) for `&TcpStream` as well. This mutability is needed by `std::io::Read` trait. Mutability works in `TcpStream` via interior mutability.

Comment: @ÖmerErden I don't think it works via interior mutability, at least not as the term is normally understood in Rust (i.e. types based on `UnsafeCell`, such as `RefCell`, `Mutex` or atomics). It makes use of the fact that file descriptor reads don't modify `self` at all. In case of `File`, its in-memory representation is a single number, which `<File as Read>::read()` passes to `libc::read()`. While the _buffer_ certainly needs to be modified by `libc::read()`, this buffer is provided by the caller (as `&mut [u8]`), and `self` is completely untouched.

Comment: `Read::read()` requires `&mut self` because in the _general_ case reading data mutates its source, which must update the stream position, refill the buffer, etc. For example, `BufReader` really requires `&mut self`, and if one wanted to implement `Read` for `&BufReader`, they would have to use Rust-level interior mutability, and pay the run-time price.

Comment: @user4815162342  _Interior mutability is a design pattern in Rust that allows you to mutate data even when there are immutable references to that data; normally, this action is disallowed by the borrowing rules. To mutate data, the pattern uses **unsafe code** inside a data structure to bend Rust’s usual rules that govern mutation and borrowing_ ([ref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html))

Comment: @ÖmerErden There's no mutation of data in `self` by `libc::read()`. Unsafe code is technically required to call `libc::read()`, but that's only due to the inherent unsafety of FFI (`libc::read` requires a raw pointer), and unrelated to interior mutability.

Comment: @user4815162342 FFI is unsafe for many reasons including mutability, digesting socket is also a mutable action, why this doesn't satisfy the pattern?

Comment: @ÖmerErden Because nothing in the memory of `self` is being mutated. But by now it's clear that we're talking about slightly different definitions of interior mutability. My point was just that the `Read` impl for `&File` and friends doesn't carry the kind of runtime cost normally associated with interior mutability in Rust, it follows from the use of file descriptors. Semantics about what precisely is included by the phrase interior mutability is (to me) much less interesting.

Comment: @user4815162342 Well I was trying to explain the behavior with a less words, I wonder what would be a better fit

Comment: Thank you all guys, now it's much clearer what's happening.

Comment: @ÖmerErden One way to look at it is as `io::Read` providing the most _pessimistic_ signature for `Read::read()`, assuming it needs `&mut self`. For file descriptor based implementations like `File` it is unnecessary, so they use the `impl Read for &File` trick to advertise their reality: that they are thread-safe and sharing-safe without the need for explicit locking or borrowing. For them `Read::read()` requiring `&mut self` is an idiosyncrasy of the type system, not an accurate reflection of the OS primitives they end up invoking.